# Unable to Use Mongo Export Query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collecton named "**sample**" and database named  "**at**" present in Mongo DB .

```
db.sample.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "35004",
        "city" : "ACMAR",
        "pop" : 6055,
        "state" : "AL"
}
{
        "_id" : "35005",
        "city" : "ADAMSVILLE",
        "pop" : 10616,
        "state" : "AL"
}
{
        "_id" : "35006",
        "city" : "ADGER",
        "pop" : 3205,
        "state" : "AL"
}
```

I have tried using mongo export query , but i was unsuccessful , please let me know where i am doing mistake .

I have tried using below ways , but always produced an error .

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db at --collection "sample" --csv --out text.csv --fields city,state

mongoexport --csv -o /D:/test.csv -d at -c sample -f city,state,pop
```

I was getting the following error , please help

**Sun Mar 10 00:25:44 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`mongoexport` must be run from your OS command shell, not the mongo shell.

Comment: The use of OS shell must have been explicitly written in the docs. It just confuses newcomers.

Comment: how can export from mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

**Or if that doesn't work try this approach.**

If there is NO `db` or `data` folders in `\bin` folder, create them.

Then open a new terminal and run:

***for example*** - `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe"`

Leave this terminal open and minimize it.

Now open another terminal and run:

***for example*** -`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe"`

Leave open and minimize as well. Now open one more terminal and navigate to your

mongodb folder: ***for example*** `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin"`
Once in the correct filepath run whatever mongo commands you want but instead of

`mongoexport` try this `./mongoexport`

Hopefully, this may help someone.

**You should be able to run a command like:**

```
./mongoexport -h YOUR.mlab.com:PORT -d YOUR-DB-NAME -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> -o <output file>
```

**Or for the entire DB use:**

```
./mongodump -h YOUR.mlab.com:PORT -d YOUR-DB-NAME -u ADMIN-USER -p PASSWORD -o C:\Luke\I\Am\Your\Father\DestinationOfAllCollections
```