# Error regarding the execution of mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

When I'm typing **mongoexport** in my *mongoshell*, it is showing the following error,

> mongoexport

```
Fri Nov 22 10:07:18.614 ReferenceError: mongoexport is not defined.
```

Please help me in this issue?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314625/unable-to-use-mongo-export-query

"mongoexport must be run from your OS command shell, not the mongo shell."

Answer (score 3):

This is for **windows machine**

mongoexport must be run from your **OS command shell**, not the mongo shell.

Go to command prompt : ( cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin ) for x64 machine

> mongoexport --help

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14773078)

Comment: Sure, Thanks will change it